# WPF Resource Styles not showing first time

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I bind my collection to the following window and usercontrol, the styles do not work.

When I press a button on the window, the styles kick in.

What is stopping my styles from firing at initial bind?

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="LbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SomeViewModel}">
                <control:SomeView Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:AnotherViewModel}">
                <control:AnotherView Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

And I have a user control as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static 
                RelativeSource.Self}, Path=DataContext.Selected}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        Red
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static 
                RelativeSource.Self}, Path=DataContext.Selected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        DarkSeaGreen
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Command="{Binding SelectCommand}"  Content="+" HorizontalAlignment=
        "Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=
        "{Binding Endorsement.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Command="{Binding DeselectCommand}" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment=
        "Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your `DataTrigger` is looking for a property in the `DataContext`... where are you setting this `DataContext`?

Comment: The usercontrol shows withe correct data in the grid, so I thought the data context would is set on the user control, else nothing would show. Is that not, right? Yeah, I'm a n00b.

Comment: Can you show us how you have set it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads and when the 'Selected' is set is two different times; hence selected is null when the page loads and nothing happens. Anticipate the null situation such as an added style

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static 
                RelativeSource.Self}, Path=DataContext.Selected}" Value="{x:Null}">
  ...
```

Comment: @hiding.ape As to binding a better way might be to set the page's data context in code behind. If interested, check out my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) (I have no ads on the site).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do this in your DataTrigger binding:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static 
            RelativeSource.Self}, Path=DataContext.Selected}"
```

A binding by default is referencing the DataContext so the equivalent simpler form is this:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Selected}"
```

I don't think that will solve your problem though (but if it does that's great). One way around it is to define a default value in the style for your Foreground if neither trigger fires:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Style.Triggers>
        ...
```

This assumes that all your items are deselected upon load. Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: Thanks too.  This was a copy/paste error.  Like i said before, I'm a n00b. So am more a forager than a coder at the moment :)